# Flex: parentDocument inconsistent between SDK version 4.1 and 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I'm seeing some inconsistencies with `parentDocument` between Flex SDK 4.1 and 4.5.  In a nutshell, existing code that works in 4.1 is broken in 4.5 (and 4.6).  Here's a small example to demonstrate:

**TestProject.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="500" minHeight="500" xmlns:local="*">

    <local:SubComponent x="50" y="50"/>
</s:Application>
```

**SubComponent.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         width="200" height="200">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.components.Application;

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var app:Application = this.parentDocument as Application;

                if (app != null) {
                    trace('Good');
                } else {
                    trace('Bug');
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button x="18" y="20" label="Button" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:Group>
```

With the 4.1 SDK, I'm successfully able to retrieve the `Application` object via `parentDocument`.  However, this fails with the 4.5 SDK.  With 4.5, `parentDocument` is now a skin object:

```
"parentDocument"    spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin (@9d7e479)
```

If I go up two levels, then I successfully get the Application object:

```
"parentDocument.parentDocument"    TestProject (@9d7e0a1)
```

So, I could work around the problem by replacing `parentDocument` with `parentDocument.parentDocument`.  However, I'm not clear whether this change is expected behavior that I can count on being consistent going forward, or if it's a bug that will likely be fixed sometime in the future, at which point the behavior will revert to the 4.1 way of doing things.  So, my questions are:

1. Has anyone else run into this issue?  If so, how did you handle
   it?
2. If you have developed a workaround, does your solution depend on
   a specific SDK version, or does it work for all SDK versions?
3. Was the change in behavior from 4.1 to 4.5 intentional, or is
   this a bug?  I suspect bug, but I've been unable to find anything
   definitive one way or the other.

Note that my example above is contrived to demonstrate the problem with the least amount of code and minimal complexity.  In my actual project, I have a module that contains a `TitleWindow` with subcomponents, and I'm trying to have the subcomponents call methods in the `TitleWindow` (via `parentDocument`).  So, workarounds that involve other ways of finding the `Application` object aren't really applicable because the subcomponents are actually looking for a `TitleWindow`, not the `Application`.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this isn't a bug. This is actually a "feature" of the spark components. Basically, for SkinnableContainers (which TitleWindow is) the children are actually added to the contentGroup of the components skin. There are a few good articles explaining it all [at this link](http://flexponential.com/2009/12/08/differences-between-ivisualelement-parent-and-ivisualelement-owner/) and [also this one](http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/?p=296).  You can probably quickly change your code to the .owner property (as long as the child object is a DisplayObject) in many scenarios to achieve the result you want.  A better approach might be to refactor some of your code to better fit with the view encapsulation that skins provide (have the child components fire events rather than trying to access methods on the parent... that kinda thing). it's pretty cool stuff once you understand all of the inner workings of skins though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  There's definitely some good info there.  Your point that children of spark components are actually added to the contentGroup of the skin makes sense.  But I'm still confused why the behavior of `parentDocument` changed between 4.1 and 4.5.  If it's a spark thing, then it would make sense that 3.x and 4.x are different, but I would expect 4.0 - 4.7 to be consistent.

Comment: Well not 100% sure on that one.  Probably... in the change docs I noticed comments like "improvements to spark framework".  I would guess that the fact that .parentDocument used to point to the component was done as a convenience method for legacy support (like your case). And as an "improvement" at some point, they had it be more consistent with the framework.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely changed between 3.x and 4.x. It may have gotten more exciting between the point releases too. Some details here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e3a.html

Comment: Well, "exciting" is a little different than the word I had in mind :-).  I've read the documentation you linked to, and although it's a bit vague, it sure sounds like the 4.1 SDK is correct, and the later versions are not.