# Cannot change the state of another component

Tags: apache-flex

I have the following function for changing state in the FYPadminSideV3 Component. But, seem not working even dispatch a event to the FYPadminSideV3 Component and calling the .currentState function form the FYPadminSideV3 Component. Anyone know the reason??

```
        protected function logoutButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{

            //set currentState="Login"; in main
            var logout:Event = new Event("logout", true, true);
            var mainComp:FYPadminSideV3 =new FYPadminSideV3();
            logoutButton.dispatchEvent(logout);

            mainComp.currentState="LOGIN";
            //set state = Out; in there
            this.currentState="Out";

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you never added mainComp to the displayList anywhere.  i.e..  myApp.addChild(mainComp).  So although you changed it's state, you can't see it until you add it somewhere.

Comment: I am quiet confuse about the .addChild() function and how the display list work. the manual said "When you add any visual element to the Stage, that element becomes a child of the Stage object.". Actually, What do this statment means?

Comment: read my answer on this post.  I have a few links in it that dive deep into child objects and their relationships in the display list.  [Other Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133389/flex-parentdocument-inconsistent-between-sdk-version-4-1-and-4-5/13153032#13153032)